# How to do a gps map-matching with graphhopper for a bicycle-track

Tags: java, graphhopper

I need to match gps-tracks recorded by bicycle to openstreetmap. For this I use the [map-matching](https://github.com/karussell/map-matching) extension for graphhopper. The routing default is for car, however there is a parameter `vehicle=`

I tried
`./map-matching.sh action=import datasource=./map-data/*.osm.pbf vehicle=bike`

and got the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encoding does not match:
Graphhopper config: bike|speedFactor=2.0|speedBits=4|turnCosts=false
Graph: car|speedFactor=5.0|speedBits=5|turnCosts=false, dir:./graph-cache/
        at com.graphhopper.storage.GraphHopperStorage.loadExisting(GraphHopperStorage.java:1410)
        at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.load(GraphHopper.java:757)
        at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.importOrLoad(GraphHopper.java:601)
        at com.graphhopper.matching.MapMatchingMain.start(MapMatchingMain.java:56)
        at com.graphhopper.matching.MapMatchingMain.main(MapMatchingMain.java:38)
```

What does this error mean? For car it worked without any problems:

`./map-matching.sh action=import datasource=./map-data/*.osm.pbf vehicle=car`

```
2015-04-30 10:29:37,624 [main] INFO  com.graphhopper.GraphHopper - version 0.5|2015-04-22T18:00:26+0000 (4,12,3,2,2)
2015-04-30 10:29:37,641 [main] INFO  com.graphhopper.GraphHopper - graph GraphHopperStorage|car|RAM_STORE|2D|NoExt|4,12,3,2,2,
details:edges:1 024 914(32), nodes:833 438(10), name: /(3), geo:7 254 610(28),
bounds:5.95087757596845,10.511746492499407,45.81184228834157,47.811018254109136
```

My system

```
> mvn --version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-15)
Java version: 1.7.0_79
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: de_CH, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.16.0-34-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first import GraphHopper creates the folder graph-cache for the map-matching component. This folder needs to be removed if you change the vehicle or the area to trigger a new import.

Please make sure you are using the '[official repo](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching)' not my personal fork :)

Please feel free to provide a pull request to improve the documentation/readme.